# Is there a way to create TestMethods on-the-fly for VS2017?

Tags: c#, testing, visual-studio-2017

I have a C# application built over .NET 4.6.1 (VS2017).

I am now building a test environment and would like to include user base tests.

The user provide a folder of files, each one is a seperate user test i need to run against.

I would like to create a `TestMethod` for each file to run against my application within VS2017.

Is there a way to automate such task? or the only way is to write a script to create the `TestClass` implementing a unique`TestMethod` for each file

Comment: `xUnit` theory test with parameterised tests with `InlineData` might be what you're after

Comment: @Bleep-Bloop, you should create an answer from your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `xUnit` tests using parameterised tests with `InlineData`. [Article with examples](https://andrewlock.net/creating-parameterised-tests-in-xunit-with-inlinedata-classdata-and-memberdata/)